# How to navigate an array of items with buttons

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, indexing

If I have an array of items, how do I navigate them? lets say two buttons and a div to show the current index I am on? I just wrote some basic stuff I THINK i will need but don't know the logic.

```
const items =[1,2,3]
let currentItem = 0

items.forEach((item, i) => console.log(item));


function next(){
currentItem++
}

function prev(){
currentItem--
}

<div>current index shown here<div>
<button onclick="next()">next item</button>
<button onclick="previous()">previous item</button>
```

Comment: You're off to a solid start! Your `currentItem` variable holds which ever item is currently being displayed. To be more precise, it holds the index of the current active item. Now let's say you want the next item in the array, with the index of 1. That means you need to go from 0 to 1 in your next function, e.g. just adding +1 to `currentItem`. Give it a go, i'm sure you can figure out the rest!

Comment: i think I did it, but it doesn't feel like i am using my array yet?

Comment: Sorry, i totally missed that part :) You're basically done, it's very close! There's two things left for you to figure out. If i understand your code correctly, you want to display the current index (Not the value of that index in the array), so you will need to change the content of the div to display `currentItem` (If you want to display the content, you can access it from the array with `items[currentItem]`. The last thing to do is to make sure that your `currentItem` does not go out of bounds from the size of your array. Take a look at the answer below and see if you can figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

```
const items =[1,2,3];
let currentIndex = 0;

function showCurrentIndex(i){
  if (currentIndex === 0 && i === -1){
     return false;
  }
  
  currentIndex = currentIndex + i;
  document.getElementById("yourDivId").innerHtml = currentIndex ;
}

<div id="yourDivId">current index shown here<div>
<button onclick="showCurrentIndex(1)">next item</button>
<button onclick="showCurrentIndex(-1)">previous item</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through the array without if conditions, you can use the following approach:

```js
const output = document.querySelector('#output');
const nextButton = document.querySelector('#next');
const prevButton = document.querySelector('#prev');

const items = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let currentIndex = 0;

const goToItem = (items, index) => {
  return (index + items.length) % items.length;
};

const handleNextClick = () => {
  currentIndex = goToItem(items, currentIndex + 1);
  output.innerHTML = `index: ${currentIndex}`;
};

const handlePrevClick = () => {
  currentIndex = goToItem(items, currentIndex - 1);
  output.innerHTML = `index: ${currentIndex}`;
};

nextButton.addEventListener('click', handleNextClick);
prevButton.addEventListener('click', handlePrevClick);
```

Your HTML might look like

```html
<div id="output">current index shown here</div>
<button id="next">next item</button>
<button id="prev">previous item</button>
```